# PyQT set QComboBox selection and item font color

Tags: python, pyqt, stylesheet

I'm trying to tweak up QComboBox item display settings so that they display different color.

```
Combo.setItemData(Combo.findText("Missing !"), QtGui.QColor("red" ), QtCore.Qt.TextColorRole )
```

This produces this http://s29.postimg.org/e8ygobnuf/Colors.jpg

But it does not display red it only goes red in drop down menu. How can I make it display red when selected?

Regards

Dariusz

Comment: Do you mean the font or box in red color?..after selection

Comment: On the screenshot you can see that second from bottom QComboBox has Missing text in it. It should be RED and it is white. I want that text to be RED, yeah I mean font. But it would be great to know how to deal with background too. Thanks!

Comment: But these are independent QComboBox, how do you expect to have `missing` item with same RED color?

Comment: Umh... lets put it this way. I want to put an item in QComboBox that has text "MISSING" and appear everywhere RED. If its selected by UI, or by user. The screenschot show 1 QCOmbo that has Missing on list, and another QComboBox that has that Missing selected. In list it appears red as I want. But when is selected it appears white...